# How to export an minified/optimized svg from Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg

I'm using Inkscape to create and manipulate SVGs. Later I use this files in my websites. Unfortunately Inkscape produces a really messy SVG, even I select `Plain SVG` in the save dialog.

[image: Messy SVG]

How can I export a clean, optimized and minified SVG from Inkscape? Like without this metadata and unnecessary transforms?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In the **Save As** dialog select the file type to be:

```
Optimized SVG (.svg)
```

You then get a dialog where you can set which optional SVG elements can be excluded.

Answer (score 5):

The built-in Optimized SVG exporter uses [Scour](https://github.com/scour-project/scour) and does a decent job.

However, running the file through [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) usually optimizes the file even further, and has the benefit of a live preview, so you can see the effect the optimizations are having. Worth trying if you're optimizing for the web.